# How create single pdfs out of one automatically?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have a pdf file containing multiple pages. I could use a script that copies every single page out of this file into a new file. E.g. 40 pages in one file in, out: 40 files each 1 different page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install PDFtk - The PDF Toolkit from http://www.pdflabs.com/

```
pdftk filename.pdf burst
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [PDF Split & Merge](http://www.pdfsam.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat Pro has the capability of extracting pages as individual files. The down side is that the software costs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdfjam` or `pdfseparate` The following commands extract pages 2-38

```
# alternative: pdfjam
for c in {2..38}; do pdfjam your.pdf $c; done

# alternative: pdfseparate
pdfseparate -f 2 -l 38 your.pdf
```